# APC AP9606 web-demo

Tags: apc-smart-ups

Where can i find a demo of the web-interface for the smart card AP9606 from APC (i'm interested in geting a glimpse at the features and see if i can use it with my current newer version APC ups's) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the AP9606 has been discontinued. Oddly enough, there is a web demo of the new management cards.

http://testdrive.apcc.com/card.htm#9630

Comment: yes. i know it's been discontinued, but i wanted to see what features are enabled in the old model. i am planning on buying a couple of this old AP9606 refurbished 10 times cheaper than new generation ones. and would like to see if they live up to the job :)